# Area below a curve defined with respect to another curve

Tags: integration, geometry, definite-integrals, graphing-functions, hyperbolic-functions

Let $a \in (-\infty, -1]$ , $c \in \mathbb R_+$ and $d \in (0,1)$ be constant real numbers. We define the parabola : $$ f(x) := ax^2 + c$$ For all $m \in \mathbb R$, we also define the geometric line $y = t_m(x)$ that is tangent to the parabola in the point $(m, f(m))$ : $$ \begin{align}t_m(x) &:= f(m)+f'(m)\left(x-m\right) \\\\ &= (am^2+c) + 2am(x-m) \\\\ &= (2am)x + (c-am^2) \end{align} $$

For each point $T_m = (m, f(m))$ , we let $Q_m$ be a point such that:

- $\Vert \overrightarrow{T_mQ_m}\Vert$ = d
- $\overrightarrow{T_mQ_m} \perp t_m(x)$
- $Q_m$, is closer to the $(Ox$ and $(Oy$ axes than $T_m$ (or more informally stated, $Q_m$ is selected so that it lays "inside" the parabola)

(it is guaranteed that $Q_m$ exists for any $m \in \mathbb R$)

Let $g = \{ Q_k : k \in \mathbb R\}$ be a function represented as a collection of these points.

Plotting the function $g$ indicates that the function is continuous and even, presenting geometric tangent lines $y = \tau_m(x)$ which are always parallel to the respective tangents $y = t_m(x)$ of $f$, for all $m \in \mathbb R$.

I am interested to know:

1. Can $g(x)$ can be exactly given by a mathematical expression? (it is a parabola / a hyperbola / etc.)
2. Given $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ such that $g(\alpha) = 0$, what is the area between the geometric elements $x=-\alpha$, $x=\alpha$, $y=0$ and $y=g(x)$? (that is, the integral of $g(x)$ above the ($Ox$ axis and between the zeroes of the function $g$).

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is nothing "informal" about referring to the inside of a parabola. It is a well-defined concept. And "$Q_m$ is the result of moving from $(m. f(m))$ by a distance $d$ along the normal to the parabola towards the interior" would be a more easily understood and mathematically precise way of defining the point. An orgasm of formulas is not necessary.

Comment: The answer for 1. is yes, but it isn't pretty. A little playing with vectors gives the equation $$g\left(m + \frac{2amd}{\sqrt{1 + 4a^2m^2}}\right) = am^2 + c -\frac d{\sqrt{1 + 4a^2m^2}}$$so if you set $x =m + \frac{2amd}{\sqrt{1 + 4a^2m^2}}$ and solve for $m$, then plug in that exprssion for $m^2$ into the right hand side, you get the formula you are after. Unfortunately, solving the equation for $m$ requires solving a [quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation#The_general_case). You do it using radicals, but it is nasty.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for taking your time to write this solution. Could you write it step-by-step as a direct answer to the question so I can vote it as the correct solution?